# How to use the ListActivity in the new Android Project Template?

Tags: android, listactivity

Since the new Android SDK Update I have a `ActionBarActivity` for my MainActivity.

Before that is was a normal activity and I just replaced it with the: `ListActivity`

How can I add use the `ListActivity` in my new MainActivity which is a `ActionBarActivity`?

Comment: this update of adt is creating a lot of confusion to developers probably the want to encourage developers to use Fragments more. ANy way you can use `extends ActionBarActivity` and have a `ListFragment`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of `extends ActionbarActivity` and `extends ListActivity`. You could also use `ListFragment`.

You can extend `ActionBarActivtiy` and use `ListFragment` from the support library

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ListFragment.html